# Integrating $\frac{x^3}{e^x-1}$

Tags: calculus

I was told that $$ \int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^3}{e^x-1}dx=\frac{\pi^4}{15}$$ in physics class.

I have no idea to compute this integral by hand. Could someone help me?

Comment: Did you get the answer you wanted? If not I actually made a page all about this and can explain more if needed. Contact me if you want better insight into this integral. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Expand
$$\frac{x^3}{e^x-1}=\frac{x^3e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^3e^{-nx}$$
and then integrate termwise.